# Possible to write C# DLL (plugin) for a C++ application?

Tags: c#, c++, plugins, interop

I'd like to write a plugin (DLL) for a C++ application but I'd like to use C#.  Is this possible?  I don't have access to the C++ code so I can't modify it.

From what I've gathered, the C++ (host) application just makes calls to different functions.

Here's a C++ sample plugin function:

void On_Start(HINSTANCE hInstance, HWND hWnd, BOOL bLogSet, int nDLLID, char * szHotKey)

How would this translate to a C# DLL that can be loaded from this C++ application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly, but you could write a shim in C++/CLI that exports the native function then delegates the actual implementation to a C# assembly.

Keep in mind, however, that this is *probably* a bad idea -- only one version of the CLR may run in a given process, so if someone else writes a managed plugin for the C++ application that targets a different version of the CLR than your plugin does, then fatal runtime errors will result.

Comment: @SofaKng : This is precisely the reason C++/CLI exists in the first place, so any C++/CLI tutorial will likely cover something similar.

Comment: as of Framework 4.0 they now support multiple versions of the CLR loaded into a single process, see the terms In-Process Side-by-Side or In-Proc SxS. One of the use cases for this was specifically for plug-ins as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

[This project](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) Creates dll exports for static methods in classes. This might be a cleaner solution.